# Quando vale a pena pagar pelo SQLServer ou Oracle?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, oracle

Bancos de dados *open-source* como o MySQL e Postgres são tão avançados que conseguem atender uma grande variedades de aplicações sem problemas, talvez a maioria. (Tem o SQLite também, mas esse é mais pra quando a portabilidade é essencial)

Mas para aplicações empresarias, principalmente, normalmente se opta por investir no SQLServer ou Oracle. Sei que os sites da rede StackExchange usam o SQLServer.

1. Que vantagens esses bancos pagos oferecem que os *open* não oferecem?
2. Em que situações é recomendado o investimento? (E quando não é?)

Comment: Boa pergunta, aqui na empresa usa-se tudo *open-source*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível escalar bancos de dados *Open Source* (SQL e NoSQL) tanto quanto uma versão comercial.

Um exemplo disso é o [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), que substitui o MySQL para aplicações de alta escalabilidade e desempenho.

Além disso, empresas gigantes usam bancos NoSQL ou mesmo SQL em clusters para prover os dados necessárias.

O que geralmente diferencia uma solução comercial é a quantidade de recursos oferecidos, que são imensamente maiores em bancos como Oracle e SQL Server do que em MySQL ou PostgreSQL, por exemplo.

Além disso, empresas como Microsoft e Oracle oferecem uma pilha de soluções integradas, enquanto nas soluções *Open Source* você iria ter que configurar e integrar tudo "manualmente", gerando custos às vezes maiores com benefícios menores.

Lembre-se, para as empresas é tudo uma questão de custo-benefício. E envolve também a questão de ter uma "segurança" de que o produto vai funcionar. Aí chegamos à questão de suporte técnico.

Para uma empresa, um sistema gratuito que não funciona é mais caro do que um sistema pago que funciona. Quando alguém paga uma licença do Oracle ou SQL Server ele está comprando a garantia dessas grandes empresas de que *bugs* serão prontamente corrigidos e suas dúvidas serão sanadas rapidamente, de acordo com SLA estabelecido em contrato.

Note, entretanto, que isso é comum para empresas de desenvolvimento "normais". Gigantes de TI como Google e outras, que costumam criar e apoiar novas tecnologias, podem se dar ao luxo de usar somente *Open Source* porque eles tem a mão-de-obra e os recursos necessários para criar infraestrutura própria e suportar tudo isso.

Nesse ponto, para eles é vantagem ter um engenheiro super especializado para lidar com os problemas das ferramentas dentro da própria empresa. Para a maioria dos negócios, entretanto, essa não é uma opção.

Answer (score 3):

Tipo da pergunta difícil de responder mas basicamente depende do quanto crítico é o Sistema, Oracle é atualmente escalável podendo o BD crescer.

Soluções acopladas como DW, Web etc também devem ser levadas em conta.

```
Que vantagens esses bancos pagos oferecem que os open não oferecem?
```

Você sabe que o BD terá continuidade.
Estas empresas são obrigadas a oferecer mais soluções que os Open Source

```
Em que situações é recomendado o investimento? (E quando não é?)
```

Aí depende, não creio existir uma "bala de prata"